Unable to save the comma separated values in jquery select 2 plugin
Unable to save and fetch the comma separated options into and from the DB(SQL). For example if a user select an option from the drop-down which contains comma or period operator(Ex:Vig,kumar mv) it didn't work. If we have the space between the first and last names like attfirst attlast it works. Please look at the attached screenshot.
I'm expecting to save the comma separated values for the single option to be saved into the database.
enter image description here
